# Java change cursor to image

Tags: java, image, cursor

How do i change cursor to my image "picture_one.jpg" in Java?
Replacement for constructor `new Cursor(Image i)` which doesn't exist woudl be enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at 
java.awt.Toolkit's [createCustomCursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String%29)(Image cursor, Point hotSpot, String name) method?